# Delete Button covers the text in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` in which i have used Autolayout feature .
Now when i am trying to delete a particular row, the delete button covers my Custom Cell Right label .

Its working fine without auto layout using structs and springs but not with auto layout.
I have used auto layout in my whole project so can't remove that feature .

image for the description : [image: http://f.talk.to/3afcd0c1376910337a36ba6d]

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftWidth`.

```
[yourLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Comment: well i wish it could have worked but its not working at my end :( . I have 2 constraint at my Right lable 1. Trailing space to superview and 1 for top space from super view . what else do i need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have xib then go to xib inspector go to properties.. uncheck the use auto layout and go to inspector and set the autosize property image will be there set the boundaries and uncheck the lines inside the box.. Hope this helps.